# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pystan in Anaconda distribution. How to fix this error?

Tags: python, python-wheel, anaconda3, pystan, u8darts

When trying to install Darts library its dependencies Pystan and Prophet were throwing errors:

- ERROR: Failed building wheel for pystan
- Building wheel for prophet (setup.py) error

Followed solution from [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan2/issues/706?msclkid=aba673baac2d11ec8483999ed008e81f) which redirected me to the pystan docs, https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html, which does not work.

How to solve this error? I would like to install Darts library successfully in Windows system Anaconda distribution.

Python 3.9.7

Comment: What exactly did you do, and what happened, and what did you expect to happen instead? What errors do you get? What is your question?

Comment: I got the error when trying to import libraries for installing Darts. I tried to resolve the error and successfully installed Darts after following the solution that I wrote.

Is the question and solution not explanatory @Robert? I could edit to elaborate maybe.

Comment: To install Prophet post pystan use the below line of code:

conda install -c conda-forge prophet

Answer (score 1):

The link that I share in the question directed me to an incorrect path for troubleshooting pystan installation for Windows. The correct link is https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html?msclkid=eb5dcb49ac2511ec829bf25d2eab26d6

When following all the steps from the above link I was successfully able to fix the issue. Also reiterating the steps I followed here.

1. conda info
2. conda update conda
3. conda activate my_env (I already had an environment created from Anaconda UI with python 3.9.7)
4. activate my_env
5. conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
6. conda install numpy cython matplotlib scipy pandas -c conda-forge
7. pip install pystan

Answer (score 0):

Please install the prophet, then import as like.

from prophet import Prophet